# php splitting records in multiple pages is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, record, split

i'm facing problem in getting the apprpriate values for some cells ....In the first page i'm getting the appropriate result..but   in the next pages the values for product information,total price and profit from order all have value 0 but all the other fields are containing correct information.

Five records are shown  per page.. The code is given below:

```
    <?include"dbconnect.php"?>
session_start();
?>
    <?include "adminhead.php"?>
    <?include "adminleftnav.php"?>
<div id="seasonal">
    <table width="635" border="0" align="left"  bgcolor="#CCCCCC" >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="635" border="0" align="left"  >
                    <tr>
                        <td width="52" bgcolor="#E0EBED">Order Number</td>
                        <td width="150" bgcolor="#E0EBED">Product Information</td>
                        <td width="100" bgcolor="#E0EBED">Total Price(TK)</td>
                        <td width="90" bgcolor="#E0EBED">Order Date</td>
                        <td width="80" bgcolor="#E0EBED">Payment Status</td>
                        <td width="100" bgcolor="#E0EBED">Profit from order(TK)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

              <?php
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
    $start_from = ($page-1)*5 ;
    $sql = "Select distinct order_no,date,payment_status from product_order_info order by order_no ASC LIMIT $start_from,5";
    $query_for_order1 = mysql_query ($sql);
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="foo" border="1" bgcolor="#f4eddb"   cellspacing="2"  cellborder="2" width=635>




                    <?  while($row_for_my_order1=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_order1))
                    {
                      ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=52>
                      <?echo $row_for_my_order1['order_no'];?>
                        </td>
                        <td width=156>

                      <?
                       $sql1 = "Select * from product_order_info  where order_no= '$row_for_my_order1[order_no]' order by order_no ASC LIMIT $start_from,5";

                        $query_for_order = mysql_query($sql1);

                         while($row_for_my_order=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_order))

                         {
                             $query_for_product_details=mysql_query("select * from  product where product_no='$row_for_my_order[product_id]' ");
                             $row_for_product_details=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_product_details);
                           ?>
                            <br>
                          <?echo $row_for_product_details['product_name'];
                          ?>
                            <br>
                            Quantity
                          <?echo $row_for_my_order['quantity'];
                          }
                          ?>
                        </td>
                        <td width=106>
                          <?
                          $total=0;
                          $sql1 = "Select * from product_order_info  where order_no= '$row_for_my_order1[order_no]' order by order_no ASC LIMIT $start_from,5";

                        $query_for_order = mysql_query($sql1);



                          while($row_for_my_order2=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_order))
                            {
                             $query_for_product_details=mysql_query("select * from  product where product_no='$row_for_my_order2[product_id]' ");
                             $row_for_product_details=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_product_details);

                            $total = $total+ $row_for_product_details['sell_price'] * $row_for_my_order2['quantity'];

                             }
                          echo $total;
                      ?>
                        </td>
                        <td width=90>

                     <?echo $row_for_my_order1['date'];?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                       <?echo $row_for_my_order1['payment_status'];?>
                        </td>
                        <td width=100>
                       <?  $total=0;
                       $sql1 = "Select * from product_order_info  where order_no= '$row_for_my_order1[order_no]' order by order_no ASC LIMIT $start_from,5";

                        $query_for_order = mysql_query($sql1);


                    while($row_for_my_order3=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_for_order))
                    {

                     $total=$total+$row_for_my_order3['profit'];
                     }

                     echo $total; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 <?
                 }
                 ?>
                </table>
</div>

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(order_no) FROM product_order_info";
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
    $total_records = $row[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 5);

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
                echo "<a href='view_order.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
    };
    ?>
    <?include "footer1.php"?>
```

Please help me in this regard...

Comment: to much code to be able to debug, i do see an issue with queries inside loops, usually a bad ideas, looks like the first query could be rewritten to get all the required data in the first place.

Comment: @Dagon please can u rewrite the first query or show me a way how to do this...

Comment: i would have to understand a lot more of what your doing to be able to help, so no.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete `LIMIT $start_from,5` from every query except the first one. As Dagon pointed out, you should consider the possibility to use a single query, to reduce the number of queries to the SQL server.